# Обратиться к первому элементу дочерного объекта

Tags: html, css

Пытаюсь назначить свойство первому элементу, в данном случаи `<img>` и `<i></i>`

```css
.all>*>img:first-of-type,
.all>*>i:first-of-type {
  width: clamp(25px, 10%, 30px);
}
```

```html
<div class='all'>
  <div>
    <img>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <a>
    <i></i>
    <div></div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Как выполнить это без конкретной привязки.

---

```css
.all > * > *:first-of-type
```

В данном случаи присваивается свойство всем дочерним элементам

Comment: Назначается на все элементы, а необходимо только на первый...

Comment: Как вы бы ответили на свой вопрос? Заголовок: "не удается выполнить". Описание: "пытаюсь, не выходит, в чем дело?". Что пытайтесь, что не выходит, что должно выходить?

Comment: [Отредактируйте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1488552/edit) вопрос. Опишите нормально в чём проблема.

Comment: Отредактировал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
div.all>*>*:first-child {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='all'>
  <div>
    <img alt="IMG">
    <div>DIV</div>
  </div>
  <a>
    <i>I</i>
    <div>DIV</div>
  </a>
</div>
```